# Multiple UI threads on the same window

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, thread-safety

I don't want multiple windows, each with its own UI thread, nor events raised on a single UI thread, not background workers and notifications, none of that Invoke, BeginInvoke stuff either.

- I'm interested in a platform that allows multiple threads to update the same window in a safe manner. Something like first thread creates three buttons, the second thread another five, and they both can access them,change their properties and delete them without any unwanted consequences.
- I want safe multi-threaded access to the UI without Invoking, a platform where the UI objects can be accessed directly from any thread without raising errors like "The object can only be accessed from the thread that created it". To let me do the synchronizing if I have to, not prevent me from cross-tread accessing the UI in a direct manner.

Comment: A better understanding of why might help.

Comment: Preferred language? C, C++, Java, C#?

Comment: No preffered language, any platform and language will do.

Comment: Why?  What will you be able to do with such a platform that you can't do with a single-threaded UI?  (Granted, as soon as I typed that I realised that I was asking why don't you want to be constrained which is rarely a clever question to ask but anyway, specifically why?  Is it just that you can't be bothered with it or is there some architectural reason that makes it unacceptable?)

Comment: So I could have distinct workflows in each thread updating the interface, without a single point of failure in a unique UI thread. Think of it as a browser window with frames, each thread updating its own UI frame. Also, this would allow for repurposing UI controls when I decide to close a thread and open another, without having to hard-code this change in a single place (a *single* UI thread) - in my opinion, UI should only display what I tell it to, in a thread-agnostic way - when i say `textBox1.text = "Name"`, I shouldn't care what thread this instruction came from.

Comment: I think you're assuming that what you want to do cant be done with a single gui thread.  Most gui frameworks make it easy for worker threads to interact with the gui.  In fact is it generally bad sytle to do any serious computation in the gui thread.  Worker threads, say 'make button blue'.  That message is enqueued behind the scenes in the worker thread.  The gui thread dequeues the message and makes the button blue.  Complicated, yes, but easily hidden with encasulation.  QT does this, and I believe C# does it as well.

Comment: If it were that easy... then any platform would do just that!
But in real-life this could bring deadlocks, performance issues (code much slower if cross-thread) or inconsistant state UI...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make a thread-safe Producer/Consumer queue of delegates.
Any thread that wants to update a UI component would create a delegate encapsulating the operations to be performed, and add it to the queue.
The UI thread (assuming all components were created on the same thread) would then periodically pull an item from the queue, and execute the delegate.

Comment: I don't want a single "UI Thread", I want a platform where any thread is an UI thread, every thread I create could directly update the interface.

Comment: Then make a queue per UI thread.  That way, other threads are free to put items in the queue without worrying about concurrency, and each UI thread can fail separately without affecting the others.

Comment: It's an interesting idea, perhaps the platform I'm looking for would implement all these queues in the background, hidden from the programmer, so I would still keep the same syntax when updating the UI from any of my threads, without being actively aware that my UI update calls are being queued. Edit your answer a bit, so I can remove the downvote, the multiple queue implementation actually helped me directing my searches towards something more specific. Thanks!

Comment: +1: one UI thread doing the UI calls, and a message passing system via queues to send update commands from the worker threads to the UI thread, and control state back the other way, looks like the way to go to me.

Comment: I do something similar and it can be expanded a lot to make it very easy to communicate back to the UI.

Answer (score 17):

I'm gonna get down voted but ... Go Go Gadget Soapbox.

Multi threaded GUI are not possible in the general case.  It has been attempted time and time again and it never comes out well.  It is not a coincidence that all of the major windowing frameworks follow the single threaded ui model.  They weren't copying each other, it's just that the constraints of the problem lead them to the same answer.  Many people smarter than you or i have tried to solve this.

It might be possible to implement a multi-thread ui for a particular project.  I'm only saying that it can't be done in the general case.  That means it's unlikely you'll find a framework to do what you want.

The gist of the problem is this.  Envision the gui components as a chain (in reality it's more like a tree, but a chain is simple to describe).  The button connects to the frame, connects to the box, connects to the window.  There are two source of events for a gui the system/OS and the user.  The system/OS event originate at the bottom of the chain (the windowing system),  the user event originate at the top of the chain (the button).  Both of these events must move through the gui chain.  If two threads are pushing these events simultaneously they must be mutex protected.  However, there is no known algorithm for concurrently traversing a double linked list in both directions.  It is prone to dead lock.  GUI experts tried and tried to figure out ways to get around the deadlocking problem, and eventually arrived at the solution we use today called Model/View/Controller, aka one thread runs the UI.

Comment: I don't want a general case where this would be standard and safe, I want a platform where it would be *allowed*.

Comment: +1 for the Inspector Gadget reference - and the concise explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe a platform like that exists *per se*

There is nothing stopping you from saying taking .Net and creating all new controls which are thread safe and can work like that(or maybe just the subset of what you need) which shouldn't be an extremely large job(though definitely no small job) because you can just derive from the base controls and override any thread-unsafe methods or properties.

The real question though is why? It would definitely be slower because of all the locking. Say your in one thread that is doing something with the UI, well it has to lock the window it's working on else it could be changed without it knowing by the other thread. So with all the locking, you will spend most of your drawing time and such waiting on locks and (expensive) context switches from threads. You could maybe make it async, but that just doesn't seem safe(and probably isn't) because controls that you supposedly just created may or may not exist and would be about like

```
Panel p=new Panel();
Button b=new Button();
WaitForControlsCreated(); //waits until the current control queue is cleared
p.Controls.Add(b);
```

which is probably just as slow..

So the real question here is why? The only "good" way of doing it is just having an `invoke` abstracted away so that it appears you can add controls from a non-UI thread.

I think you are misunderstanding how threads really work and what it takes to actually make an object thread safe

Comment: "taking .Net and creating all new controls which are thread safe"... What is stopping me is the inability to have more than one UI thread, and to put buttons on the interface directly from, say, a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Ok, well if your feeling ambitious, I know that SDL allows multiple threads to draw on a framebuffer(probably possible to get multi threaded event handling going somehow even). I wouldn't recommend creating your own controls for the faint of heart though.

Comment: "AWT 1.0" (Ohh... the deadlocks didn't happen *all* the time!)

Comment: The fact that deadlocks happen at any time still would scare me away from it

Answer (score 2):

Accept that any code updating the GUI has to be on the GUI thread.
Learn to use BeginInvoke().

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, [Window handles have thread affinity](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/10/10/479124.aspx). This is a limitation of the Window manager. It's a bad idea to have multiple threads accessing the same window on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised to see these answers.

Only the higher level language frameworks like C# have thread restrictions on GUI elements.

Windows, at the SDK layer, is 100% application controlled and there are no restrictions on threads except at insignificant nitty gritty level. For example if multiple threads want to write to a window, you need to lock on a mutex, get the device context, draw, then release the context, then unlock the mutex.  Getting and releasing a device context for a moment of drawing needs to be on the same thread... but those are typically within 10 lines of code from each other.

There isn't even a dedicated thread that windows messages come down on, whatever thread calls "DispatchMessage()" is the thread the WINPROC will be called on.

Another minor thread restriction is that you can only "PeekMessage" or "GetMessage" a window that was created on the current thread.  But really this is very minor, and how many message pumps do you need anyway.

Drawing is completely disconnected from threads in Windows, just mutex your DC's for drawing.  You can draw anytime, from anywhere, not just on a WM_PAINT message.

Answer (score 0):

[BeOS / Haiku OS](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=236331448076587879&ei=_eyZSZuZE5eg2wK__p2ODg&q=haiku+tech+talk#)

Answer (score -1):

Based on my guessing of your requirement, you want a single Windows Form and having ways to execute certain routines asynchronously (like multi-threading), yes?

Typically (for the case of .NET WinForms) `Control.Invoke` / `Control.BeginInvoke` is used to a certain effect what I think you want.

Here's an interesting article which might help: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml

Comment: I've updated the question to better reflect the idea. I want safe multi-threaded access to the UI without Invoking, a platform where the UI objects can be accessed directly from any thread without raising errors like "The object can only be accessed from the thread that created it". To let me do the synchronizing if I have to, not prevent me from cross-tread accessing the UI in a direct manner.