# How to have Qt embedded into another app (non-blocking way)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am using a 3D rendering C++ API and want to use Qt to display GUIs on top of it.

My rendering API runs in the *main()* application thread, just like Qt wants.

At first I tried to run Qt in it's own std::thread and it worked perfectly fine - and I have no idea what Qt's doc means with

> As mentioned, each program has one thread when it is started. This
>   thread is called the "main thread" (also known as the "GUI thread" in
>   Qt applications). The Qt GUI must run in this thread
>   https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html

This is either plain wrong or poorly written...

My std::thread worker looks something like this:

```
int SomeClass::qt_app_worker(size_t width, size_t height, const std::string& title, const std::string& contents) {
    int argc = 0;
    QApplication app(argc, NULL);
    // QDialog here
    return app.exec();
}
```

The problem is then I can't do anything with this Qt app because if I try to create say another QDialog from the main() thread, Qt will complain I can only do this from the thread owning my QApplication (qt_app_worker).

So I'm either permanently locked out of the qt_app_worker thread, or I have to implement my own message queue for EVERYTHING Qt-related.

I sketched it with a derived QApplication class using startTimer() and then handling custom  messages in timerEvent(...) but this is just too much hassle.

I just don't understand why Qt won't let a user run it in a separate thread, hopefully I'm just missing something.

Comment: why do you think it is plain wrong? Its like some shoe seller tells you "you best wear the shoes on your feet" and you say "That is plain wrong, I can also wear them on my head", you can do it but well...

Comment: that's why it's plain wrong, because the doc says 'must' which means 'must' when it doesn't 'have to'. I guess Im picky on words and I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I don't know if it is safe to run GUIs in 2 separate threads from an OS perspective... On the base, both will pull/send OS level events, and I'm not sure if this is a good idea. see e.g. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1677785/345027

Comment: they say "must" because its their stuff, they make the rules. You can cross a red light without getting hit by a car, but still you should not

Comment: it's 'their' stuff not 'my' stuff Im the client reading the doc here, does that make sense to you? Or am I supposed to actually be 'them' ? Again, you used 'should' and the doc says 'must'.  jeeezus

Comment: yes it makes sense. They give you guarentees what you can do with "their stuff" (to stay with the level of sloppyness), if you dont do what they (qt) tell you then the guarantees dont hold

Comment: still a lie, or just poorly written as I said hehe

Comment: There are probably assumptions deep in the library, that all rendering/event handling/whatever happens on the main thread. So if you want everything to work as advertised, you must abide by their rules. Sure, you can break the rules and if that works for you; fine. If it doesn't work and breaks in some weird corner case; it's *your* problem and you can't come back crying about it.

Comment: @Jesper Qt wont let me 'break their rules' because it will throw an assertion failure if I try and I'm actually 100% fine with it, I can understand this actually is good code design. In the end I have nothing to complain about - this will just be quite some work to implement a custom message queue system. And its guaranteed to work because everything happens in the same thread. Qt doesn't care which thread it is running into. If you look at the examples they are very easy to thread, the 'main' func is just a few lines. Problems arise when you try to interact with that thread from a // app.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two built-in thread-safe ways to communicate with the GUI thread (which is usually the "main thread" of Qt application, which is why it is often called main thread, and for Qt point of view it is).

- You can post events (including your own custom event subclasses) to the thread using [`QCoreApplication::postEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent).
- You can invoke methods of objects in another thread, provided you do so with `Qt::QueuedConnection` or `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` connection type using [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) (and its different overloads).

Communication the other way, from Qt to you own main thread, can happen in a few ways. I believe using `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` also allow getting a return value, but you probably don't want that blocking.... So you can just use any of the usual methods of communicating between threads, not limited by Qt, such as simply atomic or mutex-protected variables which are set from Qt, and your threads polls or otherwise reads when relevant (such as at start of every frame). Or make a simple message queue, if you want to be able to track every change and not just the state at the start of a frame or whatever.